# Change formula in cell based on selected options from drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need help in Excel 2016, where I need to make formula in cell range to change based on what is selected in drop down list.

Example in Picture 1, when month "NOV" is selected in drop down cell `B2`, then formula in cell range `B8:E8` and `B9:E9` formula changed to `=+'X:\OT Management\112023\[9021 SMelt.xlsx]Summary'!F$6+` and continued if "DEC" selected then formula will goes to `=+'X:\OT Management\122023\[9021 SMelt.xlsx]Summary'!F$6+` as in Picture 2.

Picture 1

[image: 1]

Picture 2

[image: 2]

Can someone advise how can it done?

I've spent last hours googling but didnt find further solution. Already done some VBA script to create the listing:

```vb
Sub CreateDropDownList()
Range("B2").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEPT,OCT,NOV,DEC"
End Sub
```

Comment: So use a choose() function - will pick from a list based on a choice ie your data validation - just turn it into a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DATEVALUE** function together with the **MONTH** function.
I would suggest that you make cell C2 a drop-down list for the choice of the year.

The following should give you the month as a number value, so "11" will show when you choose "NOV":

`=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-" & $B$2 & "-"&$C$2))`

To combine this into your cell, you can use **INDIRECT** and **CONCATENATE** together with the above formula(both are available from Excel 2003):

`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'X:\OT Management\",MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&$B$2&"-"&$C$2)),$C$2,"\[9021 Smelt.xlsx]Summary'!F$6"))`

**Please note a limitation regarding INDIRECT(from Microsoft's Website):**
If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, **INDIRECT** returns the **#REF!** error value.

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Seeing that you are trying to copy values that need to be added from multiple Excel files in one folder, the better option might be to use **Power Query**.

Just make sure that the ***cell being referenced is in a table***, to simplify the process and reduce the risk of errors creeping in.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p92aW.png)

I hope this gives you an idea of what to do next. All the best!

A²

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, for 2016 excel it got reference error after i use the indirect and concat function, the concat function for 2016 excel use different syntax like this '=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'X:\OT Management",MONTH(DATEVALUE("1-"&$B$2&"-"&$C$2)),$C$2,"[9021 Smelt.xlsx]Summary'!F$6"))', but it still showing reference error